# ¿Como actualizo teniendo campos vacíos en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Si tengo un formulario que me permite actualizar un correo y una foto de perfil como el siguiente:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.updateuser', $user->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">@method('PUT') @csrf

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm"><i class="material-icons">email</i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="{{$user->email}}">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01"><i class="material-icons">backup</i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" name="imagen" accept="image/*" capture>
                  <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Escoger foto</label>
                </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Actualizar</button> 
</form>
```

Luego recibo los datos en el controlador para guardar:

```
    public function updateuser(Request $request, $id){
    $userUpdate = App\User::find($id);
    $userUpdate->email = $request->email;
    $userUpdate->imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public');

    $userUpdate->save();

    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Actualizado.');
}
```

¿Como hago para que se guarde solo los campos que rellene el usuario y los que no, queden tal cual están?

Comment: ¿Es decir esta actualización modifica todos los registros de ese renglón?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes preguntar si el elemento del request esta `filled`, por ejemplo este campo

```
$userUpdate->email = $request->filled('email') ? $request->email : $userUpdate->email;

//Para los request de archivos puedes utilizar has
if ($request->has('imagen')) {
    $userUpdate->imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public');
}
```

De esta forma si el elemento viene del request se actualiza, si no, toma el valor original del modelo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo intenté en el campo de la imagen, pero no me resulta.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada para los tipo file, espero te sirva